# SimpleCart(js) Quantity limit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using simpleCart(js) to integrate shopping cart into my WordPress site.

I am selling articles and I really don't need quantity because obviously nobody wants to purchase 2 same articles and I want to prevent users from adding more than 1 article to cart.

So the question is: how to prevent adding same item more than once ?

I just can't find a solution to this on my own, so please help me (I am OK with any method as long as it works)!

Thanks !

P.S. This is very poorly documented, but the script is very light [CLICK HERE FOR LINK](http://simplecartjs.com/documentation.html)

Comment: adding some html will help us to help you better...

Comment: one way would be to dig into plugin AFAIK .. look at `simpleCart.add` method and do a cheking if the element exists in cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a case that anyone needs I've found it in .js package on line 128.

Just change the function to following (so it won't add a new quantity to existing item):

```
if( me.hasItem(newItem) ) {
        var foundItem=me.hasItem(newItem);
        foundItem.quantity= parseInt(foundItem.quantity,10);
        newItem = foundItem;
        isNew = false;
    } else {
        me.items[newItem.id] = newItem;
    }

    me.update();
    me.trigger('afterAdd', [newItem,isNew] );

    return newItem;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'beforeAdd' event and the .hasItem method:

```
simpleCart.bind( 'beforeAdd' , function( item ){
  // return false if the item is in the cart, 
  // so it won't be added again
  return !simpleCart.hasItem( item );
});
```